# libgdx overlap stop draw

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have written the following code. I would like to stop drawings once object one the collision has occurred. Unfortunately, it only stops drawing the object only when the collision is occurring and then starts drawing the object again.

To give an example of what I am trying to learn is: player collects coin, coin disappears. if the player misses coin, the coin still appears on screen.

The idea is to learn the basic concepts before I start putting things together. Copying code without understanding is no fun. Thanks in advance.

```
    batcher.begin();
    if (egg.collected) {
        batcher.draw(AssetLoader.textureEgg, eggRect.x, eggRect.y, eggRect.width, eggRect.height);
    }
    batcher.end();
```

My egg class:

```
public class Egg {
private Rectangle egg;
private Vector2 location;

public Egg(float x, float y){

    location = new Vector2(x, y);
    egg = new Rectangle(location.x, location.y, 10, 15);
}

public void update(float delta) {
    egg.x--;
    if (egg.x < -20) {
        egg.x = 137;
    };
}

public boolean collected = false;


public Rectangle getEgg() {
    return egg;
}

public boolean isCollected() {
    return collected;
}
```

}

The result of the above code is: The game crashes with following errors.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mygdx.gameworld.GameRenderer.render(GameRenderer.java:60)
at com.mygdx.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:32)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:214)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Comment: Add a member variable boolean to the coin class that tracks whether it's been collected yet. i.e. `if (eggRect.overlaps(boundingRect)) mCollected = true; if (mCollected) return; //without drawing`.

Comment: Thank you. I have just added my egg class code to my question. Would you mind elaborating on your comment above. I am not exactly sure how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Tenfour04 is right. Since collides is true when the two objects overlaps, it will stop drawing while they overlap and start to draw again. Save the return value to member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a member variable in your Egg class to keep track of whether the egg has been collected:

```
public boolean collected = false;
```

If you want to practice good encapsulation, you could make this variable private and give it a getter and setter, but I'll keep it simple like this.

Then in what appears to be your game or screen class, you need to tell the egg when it's collected:

```
if (eggRect.overlaps(boundingRect))
    egg.collected = true;
```

Now, you should only draw the egg if it is not collected:

```
batcher.begin();
if (!egg.collected){
    batcher.draw(AssetLoader.textureEgg, eggRect.x, eggRect.y, eggRect.width, eggRect.height);
}
batcher.end();
```

By the way, it's kind of weird that your Egg class extends Rectangle, but you aren't using it as a Rectangle but rather as a container for some other Rectangle. You might as well remove "`extends Rectangle`".

Comment: So what happens? Note that you want to draw it if is **not** collected. You have put the reverse.

Comment: I have changed the "true" to "false", and the game still crashes with following errors. Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mygdx.gameworld.GameRenderer.render(GameRenderer.java:60)
 at com.mygdx.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:32)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:214)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

Comment: Updated the code with latest amendments. The game just crashes.

Comment: NullPointerExceptions are usually very easy to debug. In your case, your current code never instantiates an egg.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I will google and see how to solve the NulPointerExceptions issue. This issue has taken so much of my time and I am beginning to feel I need to go back to basics. Once again, thank you for taking the time out to put me in the right direction.